# Microsoft HPC 2012 Export Charts and Reports via Powershell

Tags: powershell, reporting, hpc

I'd like to export some of the standard reports in Microsoft HPC 2012, like for example "job throughput" automatically to pdf and send this report to the users.So sending the mail would not be the problem but i can't find any command that can export this fancy reports :) i already looked up the HPC Powershell commands but none of them seems to fit. Any idea?

Thanks & Best Regards
Bernsi